# Connect4 Multiplayer With Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Im making a 2 Player connect4 game with RMI.My method checkWin() to check if a player has won is not working. If a player has won it will return `true`, else `false`. The method is correct, however its not working. The following are my classes being used in this method:
`Server` class,
`Client` class,
`Piece` class (A client has a piece to themself).
A `Piece` has a `Color` and it has a get and set color methods.
Code:

```java
// ...Rest of code...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    int column = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
    try {
        if(myTurn){
            if(server.updateBoard(column)){ 
                if(win(column)){
                    server.showWinner();
                }
                server.updateCurrentPlayer();
                server.updateTitle();
            }
// ....Rest of code...}
```

```java
@Override
public synchronized boolean updateBoard(int col) throws RemoteException {
    if(col >= 0 && col < columns){
        for(int row = rows - 1;row >=0;row--){
           if(this.board[row][col]==null){
               this.board[row][col] = currentPlayer.getPiece();
               player1.updateGui(currentPlayer.getPiece(), col, this.board);
               player2.updateGui(currentPlayer.getPiece(), col, this.board);
               currentPlayer.setBoard(this.board);
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
   return false;
}

@Override
public synchronized boolean checkWin(int col) throws RemoteException {

    //Vertical Check
    int row = 0;
    while (row < rows && this.board[row][col] == null) {
        row++;
    }
    int streak = 1;
    for (int i = row + 1; i < rows; i++) {
        if (this.board[i][col] == currentPlayer.getPiece()) {
            streak++;
            if (streak == 4) {
                return true; // Win condition met
            }
        } else {
            streak = 1;
            break; // Streak is broken
        }
    }
//...Rest of code...}
```

I have done some testing by cross checking a piece thats just being placed on the board to both the players' piece and they both dont match. Why is that when it is a player's piece that is being placed on the board in the `updateBoard()` method. Also if I call `board[][].getColor()` and `board[][]` is `null` it will get into a never ending process or a loop. The `updateBoard()` method works because both clients GUI updates and my `Piece` class does implement `Serializable`. Also `currentPlayer` is just either `player1` or `player2` depending on whos turn it is.

I tried to use `board[][].getColor() == currentPlayer.getColor()` instead but it throws me into a never ending process or a loop.

Comment: "The method is correct, however its not working:" this is is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing some interesting pieces, especially the declarations of `currentPlayer.getPiece()` and `board`.

But from the fact that you can compare `this.board[row][col] == null` I deduct that `board` is an array of some form of objects. Therefore it is very very likely that the comparison `this.board[i][col] == currentPlayer.getPiece()` is wrong because it compares object identities rather than contents. Even more suspicious if either `board` or the result of `currentPlayer.getPiece()` are transferred via RMI.

Please implement proper `equals` and `hashcode` methods (they always have to go together!), probably best that you use an IDE tool or some pattern to create their code. And use `this.board[i][col].equals(currentPlayer.getPiece())` instead so you get a correct comparison.

Comment: The board is a 2darray of Piece

Comment: So `Piece` needs the custom `equals` and `hashcode` implementation and you need to use it instead of the `==` operator (except for the `null`-check). The default `equals` method gets similar results as `==`.